# Viewing Deployed Apps in Weblogic Server

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I am new to weblogic and I would like to find out how my files are arrange in Weblogic?
I have used only Tomcat and this is the first time where I will deploy in a Weblogic Server.

In Tomcat, I could view the exploded view of my projects by looking at the Tomcat Home Directory
and the WebApps folder.  There I could view how my application css/js/resource files are deployed.

```
%TOMCAT_HOME%\webapps
```

I am looking for a similar functionality in Weblogic?  Can somebody tell me how?  Thanks

I am using Weblogic 10.3.4 by the way

Answer (score 19, accepted):

WebLogic supports several different ways of deploying applications, so the answer to your question is not very straightforward.

Typically, if you deploy a war/ear, then WebLogic will place them in the `$WEBLOGIC_HOME/application` directory. WebLogic will then explode your ear/war into a separate `wl_stage` folder that will be under your managedServer directory.

You can also use the ability of WebLogic to `autodeploy` ( not recommended for production apps ) where WebLogic will automatically explode the app.

In summary, you probably need to reach for the documentation to get all your questions answered.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/deployment/overview.html

Comment: @Kai, Hi, thanks for taking a look.. I am actually using Jdeveloper in deploying my app in the Integrated Weblogic Server.. Do you have an idea how to find this? Thanks.

Comment: You should see a $JDEV_HOME\System.11.1.your.ip.address\DefaultDomain. Under that, there should be an application directory.

Comment: i didn't find the `wl_stage` folder and also `managedServer` folder in my weblogic 12 c installation. could you please tell me where to locate it?

Comment: For me `application` folder does not exist, I am deploying through interface using "install" button and it seems that WebLogic uses that file directory.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure if you want to find out where to deploy or where applications have been deployed.
But if you want to see where are the deployed applications in weblogic, you can go to its console (e.g. localhost:7001/console) after start the server. Then follow the following steps:

1. Find and click "Deployments" label
2. Find and click your application in the right panel
3. Click "Overview" tab, then you will see "Path" in the opened information table.

Comment: So it means that there isn't one particular folder for webapps in WebLogic? Each application has its own path?

Comment: @zygimantus as Kal answered above. Weblogic supports autodeploy by exploring the convention directory. But I will recommend to deploy by indicating the directory of ear/war/etc. I deploy applications with weblogic-maven-plugin like this: mvn com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:deploy -Dadminurl=t3://localhost:7001 -Duser=weblogicUsername -Dpassword=weblogicPwd -Dsource=directory/to/your/application.ear -Dname=yourApplicationName -Dtargets=AdminServer